# how do i fix java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, performance, arraylist, android-logcat

I go to run my program and it works fine up untill i hit the enter button then it stops for about 2-3mins then crashes i know it has somthing to do with the arraylist but how do i fix it?

Here is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
// Making main variables
GLSurfaceView ourSurface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ourSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    FrameLayout v =(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Display);
    v.addView(ourSurface);
    ourSurface.setRenderer(new GLRenderer());

    // id'ing Buttons and EditText
    Button line = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LineVL);
    Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Enter);

    // Set on click listeners
    line.setOnClickListener(this);
    enter.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OutPutConversion Out = new OutPutConversion();
    DrawingTools AddL = new DrawingTools();
    EditText cl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CL);
    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.LineVL:
        info.setText("Enter x,y,z For Point 1");
        break;
    case R.id.Enter:
        for(int n=0;n<=2;n++)
        switch (n) {
        case (0):
            String Input1 = cl.getText().toString();
            AddL.AddLine(Input1);
            info.setText("Enter x,y,z For Point 2");
            break;
        case (1):
            String Input2 = cl.getText().toString();
            AddL.AddLine(Input2);
            info.setText("Press Enter Again TO See Results");
            break;
        case (2):
            n = 0;
            Out.Out();
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Here is the DrawingTools Class:

```
public class DrawingTools {
ArrayList<String> AL = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getAL() {
    return AL;
}

public void AddLine(String Input1) {
    String[] pStrings = Input1.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < pStrings.length; i++) {
        AL.add(pStrings[i]);
    }

}
```

Here is my conversion class:

```
public class OutPutConversion {
DrawingTools GAL = new DrawingTools();

public void Out() {
    String[] Result = GAL.getAL().toArray(new String[0]);
    float[] vertices = new float[Result.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        vertices[i] = Float.valueOf(Result[i]);

    }
}
}
```

And finaly here is the Logcat:

```
06-14 04:25:52.362: W/dalvikvm(22810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa41f8)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:114)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at com.example.drawingarrays.DrawingTools.AddLine(DrawingTools.java:15)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at com.example.drawingarrays.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3540)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14167)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-14 04:25:52.370: E/AndroidRuntime(22810):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please check how often the OnClick method is called.

Comment: One time for the Line button and three more for enter I'm not sure what you are meaning?

Comment: you did not return arraylist in ur  DrawingTools class

Comment: Which part of the class?

Comment: It's seems to me like when you're calling the Out.Out() method your calling getAL() on an "empty" ArrayList as you're OutPutConversion class is creating a new DrawingTools class.

Comment: @Dakota Miller: i was suspecting it keeps getting called for some reason and fills your arraylist with garbage.

Comment: How are your for-loop iteration supposed to work? Once n reaches 2, it will, inn effect, be reset to 1 (first set to 0, right afterwards incremented to 1). It seems to me that 'case(0)' is called once, and all other iterations cycles between 'case(1)' and 'case(2)'.